# Why doesn't $R(G)$ contain a torus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

$G$ is a connected linear algebraic group which is not solvable, and $T$ is a maximal torus of $G$, with $\textrm{Dim } T = 1$.  $B$ is a Borel subgroup of $G$ containing $T$, and $U$ is the group of unipotent elements of $B$.  The radical $R(G)$ is the unique maximal closed, connected, normal, solvable subgroup of $G$.  Equivalently, $R(G)$ is the identity component of the intersection of all Borel subgroups of $G$.   I have checked all the details of this lemma, except I am stuck on the last sentence.  Why can't $R(G)$ contain a torus?

[image]

This lemma comes from the book *Linear Algebraic Groups* by T.A. Springer.

If $R(G)$ contained a torus, such a torus would automatically be maximal.  So it would contain some conjugate $yTy^{-1}T$ of $T$.  But $R(G)$ is normal in $G$, so this means that it would contain all maximal tori.  I still don't see what the contradiction is.

Comment: $G= {\rm GL}_1 = T= B = R$ seems a contradiction. Am I missing something? Obviously $G$ semi-simple iff  $R=1$...

Comment: Ah sorry, I left an assumption out: $G$ is assumed to be not solvable.  I've edited the question.

Comment: It is **always** a good idea to give references to texts one refers to, and even more if one a actually includes the text!

Comment: You're right, I have edited the question.  This is from Springer's book on algebraic groups.

Comment: I guess the point is the hypothesis that the maximal torus $T$ is of dim $1$ : $G/R$ is semi-simple, not equal to $1$, hence contains a torus (of positive dim). Therefore $R$ cannot.

Comment: Okay, I get that a connected nontrivial nonsolvable group $H$ must contain a nontrivial torus: any proper Borel subgroup $B$ thereof cannot be nilpotent (by (6.2.10) of the reference), hence cannot be unipotent, hence contains a nontrivial torus by the usual decomposition $T \times B_u$.

Comment: So $G/R$ being nontrivial, connected, and nonsolvable contains a torus.  Why does that imply that $R$ cannot contain a torus though?

Comment: More directly - by hypothesis $T$ maximal torus of dim 1: so if $S$ is a (non-trivial) torus, and $S < T$, then $S = T$. Hence $S <R $ implies $T < R$ (and that $G$ is solvable). How does that sound?

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for your help.  You can post this as an answer if you want.

Comment: Your conjugate of $T$ contains too many $T$'s ($y T y^{-1}T$).